# PHP ImageMagick clean image with text

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, tesseract

I have an image with Russian text. I need to recognize a text from this image

[image]

I am using a Tesseract library. For some words it doesn't work as expected, so I want to clear the image and make a text bold and clear background for it. For Tesseract I am using this code:

```
$ocr = new TesseractOCR(__DIR__ . self::CACHE_PATH . 'header_' . $filename);
$res_rus_header = $ocr->lang('rus')->run();
if (!empty($res_rus_header)) {
    $res_rus_header = explode(PHP_EOL, $res_rus_header);
}
```

How I can clean an image before tesseract? I founded this post: https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php/issues/91#issuecomment-342290510

So, I want to try these commands to image:

```
$ convert -colorspace gray -modulate 120 -contrast-stretch 10%x80% -modulate 140 -gaussian-blur 1 -contrast-stretch 5%x50% +repage -negate -gaussian-blur 4 -negate -modulate 130 original.jpeg clean.jpeg
```

How can I do it with Imagick library?

Like this

```
$img = new Imagick(__DIR__ . self::CACHE_PATH . 'data_' . $filename);
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$img->despeckleImage();
$img->brightnessContrastImage(0.4, 100);
$img->magnifyImage();
$kernel = \ImagickKernel::fromBuiltIn(\Imagick::KERNEL_OCTAGON, "1");
$img->morphology(\Imagick::MORPHOLOGY_OPEN, 1, $kernel);
$img->writeImage(__DIR__ . self::CACHE_PATH . 'fix_data_' . $filename);
```

Thank you

Comment: Lookup similar names to your Imagemagick commands in the Imagick library at https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php. For example -modulate is modulateImage().

Answer (score 0):

Your text is too small and the characters are close together.

So here is one way by using artificial supersampling. That is enlarge the image, process with division normalization and then morphology close then minify back to original size. The division normalization part whitens your image to clean some of the jpg artifacts that would show up around your characters when the morphology is used. The morphology darkens your characters.

```
convert text.jpg  \( +clone -blur 0x3 \) +swap -compose divide -composite -resize 1000% -morphology open diamond:1 -resize 10% x2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use this command in PHP code? It looks very hard. For example, what is diamond:1? I can't find this command in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.morphology.php. Diamond is the kernel and 1 is the size of the diamond.

Comment: I received a blur image:
$clone = clone $input;
$clone->blurImage(0, 3);
$input->compositeImage($clone, 65, 0, 0);
$input->scaleImage($input->getImageWidth() * 10, $input->getImageHeight() * 10);
$kernel = \ImagickKernel::fromBuiltIn(\Imagick::KERNEL_DIAMOND, '1');
$input->morphology(\Imagick::MORPHOLOGY_OPEN, 1, $kernel, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
$input->scaleImage($input->getImageWidth() / 10, $input->getImageHeight() / 10);
$input->writeImage(__DIR__ . self::CACHE_PATH . 'fix_data_' . $filename);

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Imagick, only Imagemagick. Also it is very hard to read your comments. Can you put that into your original question? I note in your original post, you use octagon. That is too large a kernel. My comment used the diamond shape kernel. Apart from this, how is this comment code different from your code in your question?